# Having all GPIO signals and making an OR between them

Tags: gpio

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 to be used to give signal to a relay. When I was experimenting, I somehow manage to make one of the GPIO pins not working. When I use another port, it perfectly works. I don't know why this happened but most probably I shorted it somehow.

Since the Raspberry Pi will be remotely installed, it will be hard for me to change which GPIO pin is used physically. I can only change which GPIO pin to use in software remotely.

My question is, can I have a setup where I use all the signals from all GPIO pins and make an OR between them in the hardware and connect this to the relay to output the signal.

I am thinking about a female extension and somehow this female extension is connected to another hardware and then it is connected to the relay. But I do not have too much experience and do not know if such a thing exists.

PS: I know that there are different pins some of them are GRND etc. My idea is to keep a list of GPIOs and only use them. And the other end of GPIO extension will listen all of the inputs and make an OR between the signals. Can this be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  But not specific to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @joan it would be awesome if you could elaborate it :\

Comment: In correct use the GPIO pins should not be damaged - seems pointless.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer based on the statement that you used a relay not a relay module. If this is true it did what is expected it blew the GPIO pin on your pi. The GPIO port pins are designed for 3.3V logic, not external loads. What you need to do is build some type of interface such as using a MOSFET to drive the relay or a relay module that has been designed to do what you want. These modules are available from many sources and are inexpensive, much less costly than replacing Raspberry Pis after you blow all the GPIO pins with a relay.

Relays are an inductive load that will cause a transient when turned off. What happens is when the inductor (relay coil) is energized it stores energy in the coils magnetic field. When the coil is disconnected (turned off) the magnetic field collapses causing a reversal of polarity (Positive and negative polarity swap). At this point the voltage from the collapsing field will continue to rise until it is limited and the energy from the field is dissipated.

My recommendation is to Obtain or purchase a copy of the Raspberry Pi Cookbook and it will give you all the information you will need to do the interface and or select the appropriate module. Posting links to hardware items helps assure you get a correct answer and we do not have to make assumptions. If I assumed wrong and you are using a module you probably shorted it to a power supply.